# Flutter - Split child item in horizontal scroll view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i would like to create a page like the image attached below in flutter tablet app. But currently i have no idea on how to split and move the remaining content to the next container when the content reach the end height of the device screen.

[image]

Comment: would you add more details of what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use the counting line, but the other device does not work because the other device is not the same height, for example, i use lenovo device can fit 12 item, i use huawei device only can fit 8 item

Comment: I mean, please edit the question and add the code you have tried

Comment: Could you add more information or many a simple mock to illustrate the expected output that you need?